# Which files has to be added in plugins to open the hadoop mapreduce source code in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mapreduce, eclipse-plugin, ubuntu-16.04, hadoop2

Suppose I have written a follwing code in eclipse

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

Now, suppose I want to open the source code of `Job`/`Configuration` object(as obvious by clicking on it with `ctrl` pressed),eclipse throws error saying source code not found with Attach source tab.

I tried downloading few plugins but it din't work. 
Please help,Thanks in advance.

(Note: I use eclipse mars,version 2.7.2 and OS is ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Comment: Please suggest a URL where I can download from or plugin name.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to set up Map-Reduce Projects in Eclipse is by using Maven.

1. First, setup a Maven Project in Eclipse.Follow this link : https://wiki.jasig.org/display/UPM32/Creating+a+Simple+Maven+Project

2.Next, update the pom.xml file of your maven project with the below tags. You can change the version tags for Hadoop related Artifacts according to your need (2.7.2 according to your question). Make sure JAVA_HOME is set in your system env variables.

```
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
           <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
           <scope>system</scope>
           <version>1.8</version>//1.7 if you are using jdk 7
           <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

3. Right click on your eclipse project Go to Maven -> Click Update Project 
   and wait for a while. It will download all the dependent jars for executing a Hadoop Client.

4.Now, When you write your Mapreduce code, and try to view the source of any Class or Method(Job, in your case) Eclipse should not complain "source code not found with Attach source tab". You should be able to see the source code.